# Getting text of an element using text method and then checking condition but not getting appropriate output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Assignment Q1</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="style/style1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('button').click(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        console.log(text);
        if (text == 'night') {
          $('body').css('background-color', 'black');
          $(this).text('day');
          console.log(text);
        } else {
          $('body').css('background-color', 'white');
          $(this).text('night');
          console.log(text);

        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <button>
        night
    </button>

</body>

</html>
```

The thing that is happening over here is that when I am clicking on the button for the first time nothing is working ,but from the second click on wards the code is working as expected.

I have also checked what text method is getting for the first time
output:

```
    night

    night
```

and after the second click text method is getting
output:

night
night
day
day

Not able to understand what is happening over here and how text method output is changing by itself?

Comment: What's wrong with it? It seems to work.

Comment: Yes it works but when you will click on the button for the first time there is no output and after the second click every thing is working fine, I am not able to understand what is happening in the first click.

Comment: As I have noticed the spaces are automatically trimmed after the first click but is this a feature by default or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `button` looks like this in the HTML:

```
  <button>
        night
    </button>
```

The whitespace is important - when you call `.text` on the button, you get *all* the text content of the button, including the whitespace.

Either don't use any whitespace initially:

```
<button>night</button>
```

Or call `.trim()` on the resulting `text`:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Assignment Q1</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="style/style1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('button').click(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        console.log(text);
        if (text.trim() == 'night') {
          $('body').css('background-color', 'black');
          $(this).text('day');
          console.log(text);
        } else {
          $('body').css('background-color', 'white');
          $(this).text('night');
          console.log(text);

        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

      <button>
            night
        </button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note that it's always best to use `trim()` when reading text from the DOM, as it's all too easy to add an accidental return to the HTML, which makes no visible difference, but will break your JS.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the `text()` you receive from the method call has whitespace around it so it doesn't match the `'night'` string you're comparing to.

To fix this, use `trim()` to remove that whitespace:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().trim();
    if (text == 'night') {
      $('body').css('background-color', 'black');
      $(this).text('day');
    } else {
      $('body').css('background-color', 'white');
      $(this).text('night');
    }
    
    console.log(text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>
  night
</button>
```

Also note that you can improve the logic by using classes to set the styling and then `toggleClass()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('day night');
    $(this).text(function(i, t) {
      return t.trim() == 'night' ? 'day' : 'night';
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.night { background-color: #000; }
.day { background-color: #FFF; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="day">
  <button>
    night
  </button>
</body>
```